# JQuery Datatables - Get Column Filter

Tags: jquery, filtering, datatables

Is there a way in JQuery Datatables to get the current filter status of a column?  I am doing some custom filtering and have bStateSave set to true.  When the page reloads I would like to read out the current filter state in order to populate a different portion on my page.

Answer (score 6):

For anybody still looking (like I was):

```
    var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
    $("tfoot input").each(function(i){
        if(oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[i]['sSearch']!=''){
            $(this).val(oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[i]['sSearch']);
        }
    });
    if(oSettings.oPreviousSearch['sSearch']!=''){
        $('.search_field').val(oSettings.oPreviousSearch['sSearch']);
    }
```

taken from http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/992/solved-override-bstatesave-with-osearch-and-aosearchcols/p1